# How do I tell if class E airspace extends to surface or starts at 700'?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, class-e-airspace

I am confused about where class E airspace starts in the USA. If it has dotted magenta lines does it start at the surface? If small airport has round magenta circle but no dotted lines does class E start at 700'?

Comment: Welcome John. This site covers aviation question from all around the world. When asking a question about local procedures, please remember to mention which country you are asking about, since local procedures change, well, depending on the location. I am going to assume you are asking about the USA, and I have edited your answer accordingly. Please change it if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: There's an excellent web page [here](http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/airspace/class-e/) that helps explain class E.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

<sup>Source: FAA VFR chart.</sup>

The magenta dashed is from surface, the magenta gradient is from 700 ft. AGL, and the blue gradient from 1200 ft. AGL.

Comment: It is there, but I just want to point out that vast segments of the U.S. airspace have different basal starting altitudes for class E.  That is what the last image on the list is talking about.  Where I live, 1200 ft AGL is the prevailing base, but out west it is 14,500 Ft. AGL.

Comment: yeah, I would think that sounds right.

Comment: @RyanMortensen Those segments are much smaller than they used to be a year or two ago.  The FAA is significantly downsizing the large chunks of surface-14500' class G.

Comment: @pericynthion Good to know.